# Replacing a CSS class with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Similar to a previous question but I gave up on that an decided to come back to it later, now things are different as I'm using jQuery. I'm having a dropzone on my site and for image files I would like there to be a border shadow, but for files I don't want one. Multiple files can be dropped and the previews display inline, so say if 2 images and one file were dropped, I would want the shadow on both the images, but not the file preview box. I made 2 CSS classes, identical except for the shadow:

```
.dz-preview {
    background: transparent;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 40px;
    vertical-align: top;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    padding: 10px 13px 10px 10px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16);
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16);
}
.dz-preview-noshadow {
    background: transparent;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 40px;
    vertical-align: top;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    padding: 10px 13px 10px 10px;
}
```

Simplest way to go seemed to be with jQuery and I was using it in the project anyway, so I made this (.dz preview is the default class):

```
mydropzone.on("addedfile", function(file) {
    if (!file.type.match(/image.*/)) {
        $('.dz-preview').addClass('dz-preview-noshadow').removeClass('dz-preview');

        mydropzone.emit("thumbnail", file, "http://i.local.dev:5000/jLNutaV.png")

    }



});
```

It works initially-but goes wrong. I drop 2 images and they get their shadowed border just fine, but when I drop a file, it loses its shadow, which is what I wanted - but so do the two images that were dropped before it. If I drop another image it will get its shadow again, but the previous elements don't change. I know I'm missing something really stupid here about the scope of how JS is affecting these classes, but is there a way to change the class for JUST that instance, without muddling up everything before it, or do I need to run more checks and manually add the class back on?

Comment: $('.dz-preview') selects all your containers, thumbnails or whatever it is. You need to pass reference to the added element somehow, but it will be hard to help you if you won't show the code which is creating the DOM elements.

Answer (score 0):

Can't post codes in comments, so I'll make it an answer.
Since .dz-preview and .dz-preview-noshadow shares a lot of same codes, you can have a class that just holds the shadow. For eg:

```
.dz-preview {
    background: transparent;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 40px;
    vertical-align: top;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    padding: 10px 13px 10px 10px;
}
.shadow {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16);
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16);
}
```

So instead of adding and remove, you can just do a remove.